# Object gotten from the NestFactory has all the internal dependencies as undefined - NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, inversion-of-control

I get an object from NestFactory and then I call a function. There is another class injected inside service class. All the dependencies inside the service are not accessible.

```
const FASTIFY = new FastifyAdapter();
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, FASTIFY, {
        bufferLogs: true, // do wait till LoggerService is available
});
const service = app.get<ServiceClass>(ServiceClass);  // service object is obtained from container
console.log(service.anotherRepository); // repository and injected objects are undefined.
```

Service object is obtained from container and then I can see the code goes into service class but all the dependencies defined inside the service class are undefined.

I have set the scope of all of them to DEFAULT.

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.DEFAULT })
```

Comment: DO you end up injecting `REQUEST` into any of these services? Seems strange for them to be `undefined` otherwise, as that would indicate it's not yet made, which it should be

Comment: I double checked all of the internal dependencies. I changed all of them to DEFAULT scope. I am still getting them undefined. Giving it another try, thanks.

Comment: Any chance you could link to your repo?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel one of the repositories extends a generic repo, which is a class, neither used independently as an object, just used as a templatized class which is used for extension.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel something like this `export class MyRepository extends Repository<TestClass>` and that generic repo looks like this `export class Repository<T = any> {
  public constructor(private readonly knexClient: Knex | null, public readonly tableName: string) {}`

Comment: Can you get a link to your _git_ repository? So I can see the code. Something seems off here

Comment: I wish I could @JayMcDoniel it's proprietary

Comment: I would guess something _somewhere_ is making use of a `REQUEST` scoped dependency and due to scope hierarchy everything is becoming request scoped. Without being able to dig in more, I can't really see

Comment: I will spend sometime on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the classes are created with `scope: Scope.REQUEST`. You can still get the objects using

```
const serviceClass = await app.resolve<ServiceClass>(ServiceClass);
```

This has been fixed in the newer versions.